# How to remove keys and lift props up?

Tags: javascript

Given the following object:

```
{
  __proxy: {
    state: {
      count: 0
      items: {
        __proxy: {
          state: {
            amount: 0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'd like to convert it to:

```
{
  count: 0,
  items: {
    amount: 0
  }
}
```

So, as you can see, I'm doing a few things:

1. Removing `__proxy` and bringing its content up
2. Removing `state` and bringing its content up
3. All of the above recursively.

I've tried something like the snippet below:

```
const removeKeys = (obj, keys) => obj !== Object(obj)
      ? obj
      : Array.isArray(obj)
      ? obj.map((item) => removeKeys(item, keys))
      : Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).filter(([k]) => !keys.includes(k)));

removeKeys(myObj, ['__proxy', 'state'])
```

However, it completely removes `__proxy` and/or `state` - and I want to preserve their content.

That said, do you know any existing solution for that? An NPM library, perhaps? Or a lodash function?

*Note: Since I'm using TypeScript, a typed solution would be preferred, but raw js works well either.*

Thanks!

Comment: What's the typescript tag for?

Comment: Well, a typed solution is better than a raw js solution; but either way works for me.

Comment: I think @kellys was suggesting that your question has nothing to do with typescript, it's a simple javascript question (that's what tags are useful).

Comment: Done. `typescript` is removed.

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge In any case I have made the first half of the solution you seek (types): [playground](https://tsplay.dev/wjZj2w). This solution is limited and slow however. I'll work on the actual programmatic solution and optimize these types later.

Comment: Thanks, @kellys. I'm at the same pace as you are -- opened playground and started drawing. But so far, all I have are clumsy sketches. Your snippet gave me a few ideas, but still gotta dig deeper.

Comment: I've got a working strongly typed [solution](https://tsplay.dev/NnaZ6w) where the code is based off of the types. I removed the `Expand` type for debugging and now it's pretty fast.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could destructure the unwanted properties and move the content a level up.

```js
const
    convert = ({ __proxy, state, ...object }) => __proxy || state
        ? convert({ ...(__proxy || {}), ...(state || {}), ...object })
        : Object.fromEntries(Object
            .entries(object)
            .map(([k, v]) => [k, v && typeof v === 'object' ? convert(v) : v])
    )
    data = { __proxy: { state: { count: 0, items: { __proxy: { state: { amount: 0 } } } } } },
    result = convert(data);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I think I'll need to open a couple of brand new stackoverflow questions to understand well your answer to this one. :))) Brilliant.

Comment: It seems pretty simple, once you get past the destructuring syntax. What happens is if either unwanted property exists, call the function again with the same root object but without the unwanted properties, effectively flattening up a level, otherwise keep traversing the key-value pairs recursively and passing them up to be attached (or reattached) on the enclosing object.

Answer (score 1):

Usually for these problems I start on the types first. Sometimes making the type gives me ideas on how to implement it in code, so here we go!

Let's first define a type that does this (I call it "obliteration" for whatever reason) for one key only:

```
type Obliterate<O, K> = O extends object ? { [P in Exclude<keyof O, K>]: Obliterate<O[P], K> } & (K extends keyof O ? Obliterate<O[K], K> : {}) : O;
```

If `O` is not an object, there is nothing to remove from it.

However if it is, the following steps are taken:

- We omit `K` from `O` and then recursively traverse down the object and "obliterate" all the values.
- We check if `K` is a key of `O` and if it is we intersect it with the result from the first step. If it isn't we intersect it with `{}` which does nothing.

Then a type that takes a list of keys and iterates over it and uses `Obliterate` on the target:

```
type ObliterateEach<O, K> = K extends readonly [infer F, ...infer M] ? ObliterateEach<Obliterate<O, F>, M> : O;
```

If `K` is not empty, we operate on the object, otherwise we are done and return the object.

With these types I have poorly written the following code that both mirror how these types work:

```
const obliterate = <O, K extends PropertyKey>(o: O, k: K): Obliterate<O, K> => (
  (o && typeof o === "object")
    ? Object.assign(Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(o).filter(([p]) => p !== k).map(([p, v]) => [p, obliterate(v, k)])), k in o ? obliterate((o as any)[k], k) : {})
    : o
) as Obliterate<O, K>;

const obliterateEach = <O, K extends ReadonlyArray<PropertyKey>>(o: O, k: K): ObliterateEach<O, K> => (
  k.reduce<{}>((r, k) => obliterate(r, k), o)
)  as ObliterateEach<O, K>;
```

You can read these functions the same as the types above. They are the exact same steps, just in code and not types (and a few casts to suppress type errors).

This is most certainly not the *best* strongly typed solution, but it's a start.

A [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&jsx=0#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCGAnA5gU1gXhgbwFAxgH1CAHREADwE8AuHfAmaeKVOvRx0AVzCjoAMAGgacAlqwC2EdqM5FS5arPnzmrFavnxJIXvxjC5qgL4itMM8cvnGVglZMBuXLihUSqGAHkARgBsJVEQWVAAebyEYAGkAPhgsbxhUClYwABMIGBBfACtUYFgAfhwYAG0ABRgxMBgAUQpgf2508IBrVCoQADMfKLiAXTo-QNYQ1gjKgf74kxgAMhgACmjk1NQMrI6u3qSSkaDx8O8y6OmY+PYTAEoYYZc3Dy8DsdC6+GAACwiZhJi1tKZGCIVDwdLgfxUco1brBGAAMSiADoUTC4QBZAYwfYBQ5vD7fF7BUI-BGxKLoy4+B6gSCwHKjYmsP6k1YpQFZCrkTyIdzRTqxJYgYZRNp0aLXYa414TSIXBLxJYMIULRbuTw9bIJDBYABEOXyhV11zkOMNUCR8AgEDEyDASz85qR3XIkjqfEQYlQEAdeQKFo2UE93qF12dYn8YyWSzKJAGtww8RIMAAhDqYG0w5J4CRo7GogA3eMK8okKIMvGsJYF0XXePXUXVWogbHZaVM1DRltWmDwMBUa5lNrnTN3HA3OR0EC4W49olHVmxGngaBtxlHd5fFlytnrTYwABKoPBYEhAEFECEqGEuSAeXyBYLhX0M+LJT52xuCYuS0qCG0kRBdJuGAcJsBMQUlkQWsSwrGVO2gjMG2yE1bl7LJ53xL5F2XOlgW9bhIz+OCO03T4lgQFB0CiMpdWIMhKCoXUol1dRUF1LEe1paBrlwiAQH8VAkX8EBkCggjI14oA) demonstrating this solution.

Comment: Is my code so badly written that SO can't highlight it correctly lol